# MPLCONFIGDIR error in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I try to import matplotlib.pyplot I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError("'%s' is not a writable dir; you must set %s/.matplotlib to be a writable dir.  You can also set environment variable MPLCONFIGDIR to any writable directory where you want matplotlib data stored "% (h, h))
```

I do have a .matplotlib directory in my home directory which is owned by me and has write permissions on. So why is it telling me it is "not a writable dir" and how do I fix this?

Comment: what is the final output of the exception ? ie something like `RuntimeError: '/home/ranjit' is not a writable dir; you must set /home/ranjit/.matplotlib to be a writable dir.  You can also set environment variable MPLCONFIGDIR to any writable directory where you want matplotlib data stored`

Comment: Yeah %s is my home directory. So it's definitely writable.

Comment: what is the output of `ls -ld ~/.matplotlib`

Comment: I'm the owner and these are the permissions: drwxr-xr-x

Comment: I suppose you are the user who is launching the python process

Comment: Yeah, that's why this is so puzzling.

Comment: Okay problem solved. Actually it's pretty stupid. The disk was full, which is why it was reporting that my home directory wasn't writable.

Comment: funny, I just had the same problem... solution: be more careful downloading your datasets

Answer (score 4):

Don't run Python as root; it not really safe, and you will potentially just run into more permissions issues later. Instead, just make sure you own the home directory and matplotlib directory:

```
sudo chown $USER ~ ~/.matplotlib
```

Answer (score 3):

Set `MPLCONFIGDIR` to '/tmp/', as described in [this guide](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Using_MatPlotLib_in_a_CGI_script)

```
 # python
 os.environ[ 'MPLCONFIGDIR' ] = '/tmp/'
```